# 3 column layout will not display after settings are made

Tags: articles, menu, layout, category

I have created my own template and want my category articles to display in 3 columns. I have set these setting to display in 3 columns in the global configuration and the menu settings. It all still displays as one column.

www.scottiev.com/R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you haven't created the appropriate CSS support for 3 columns in your template.

For example, at the home page (or whatever it is this page: www.scottiev.com/R ), if you want to show the 3 blocks in a 3 column fashion, then you need to add something like the following css rules in your template's css file.

```
.span4 {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: you are using bootstrap.min.css v3 - but the html doesn't have the appropriate classes to work with it. Apart of building the main template's index file, you will need to create template overrides for the Joomla components and modules.

Comment: I think the tutorial I followed was meant for a previous version of bootstrap and they have since changed the classes. I will have to go in and take a closer look at my bootstrap css and change accordingly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: or you could try using the included with Joomla Bootstrap v2. You can find it in media/jui/css/

Comment: I have gotten the column to display at 33.3% but it is displaying down instead of across even though I have set the multi-column display order to display across.

Comment: Have you modified the bootstrap css? As your site was previously, the css code I gave you in my answer, would result to make the 3 columns. Anyhow, it looks like you are lacking basic knowledge - I would suggest to start learning web development from the beginning.

Comment: I have not modified the bootstrap css but have added a little bit of my own custom on a separate stylesheet. I have a good understanding of HTML/CSS and can usually find a way to get my front end development done. I am trying to learn how to build with CMS's a little better. I am not so much a developer but a designer trying to learn more. I am currently using ostraining.com for much of my learning with joomla. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Ok - for now remove your latest additions inside your css file and add what I gave you in my answer. Good luck to your learning trip.

Answer (score 0):

You should have some module(s) published into these "columns" (i.e. module positions in them), and set them to show on some menu items.
Just don't understand what settings have you set in global configuration, where there are no template-specific options?